# question about php and ajax-jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, load

i have a problem in a form. I have a simple form and the validation in a php. All works fine. Now i pass the file in a ajax load() method and appears the problem.

When i press submit the page don't show any massage, simple redirect to the initial page of the website.

i tested and the messages are shown in a separate mode without the ajax. Just using form.php

in the index.php

```
$("#replace").load("form.php");
```

in form.php

```
<?php
require_once("validation.php");
?>


  <div id="container">
        <form method="post" id="customForm" action="">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Name</label> <input id="name" name="name"
                    type="text" /> <span id="nameInfo">Insira o seu nome</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">E-mail</label> <input id="email" name="email"
                    type="text" /> <span id="emailInfo">Insira um email válido por
                    favor!</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="myPassword">Password</label> <input id="myPassword"
                    name="myPassword" type="password" /> <span id="myPasswordInfo">Insira
                    pelo menos 4 letras e sem espaços</span>
                <div id="bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="pass2">Confirm Password</label> <input id="pass2"
                    name="pass2" type="password" /> <span id="pass2Info">Confirme a
                    password</span>
            </div>
            <div></div>
            <div>
                <input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
            </div>
        </form>

        <?if( isset($_POST['send']) && (!validateName($_POST['name']) || !validateEmail($_POST['email'])
        || !validatePasswords($_POST['myPassword'], $_POST['pass2']))):?>
        <div id="error">
            <ul>
            <?if(!validateName($_POST['name'])):?>
                <li><strong>Invalid Name:</strong> Nome muito pequeno</li>
                <?endif?>
                <?if(!validateEmail($_POST['email'])):?>
                <li><strong>Invalid E-mail:</strong> Escreva um email válido por favor</li>
                    <?endif?>
                    <?if(!validatePasswords($_POST['myPassword'], $_POST['pass2'])):?>
                <li><strong>Passwords inválidas:</strong> Passwords não coicindem ou são inválidas!</li>
                    <?endif?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?elseif(isset($_POST['send'])):?>

        <div id="error" class="valid">
            <ul>
            <?if(!inserirDados($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'], $_POST['myPassword'], $_POST['pass2'] )):?><?endif?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?endif?>
    </div>
```

how i can fix this?

Comment: How do you attach the submit handler?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean with submit handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is a problem with your submit handler. Two points:

1. If you're reloading your form every time with load(), you will need to re-attach your submit() handler when it finishes loading (uses the [second parameter (callback)](http://api.jquery.com/load) to re-attach the handler)
2. You must either `return false` or call `e.PreventDefault()` in your submit handler to prevent the default behaviour of the submit button (which is to, well, submit the form).

Also, note: the reason it reloads the current page is because action="" (which means post to the current url).. and is a strong indicator that your submit handler doesn't prevent normal submission of the form

**Edit**: You attach a "submit" handler to the form to perform custom ajax stuff instead of the default behaviour. See [the jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/).

Comment: can you explain me how i can do the re-attach?, i remove the action="" and the same occurs, thanks

Comment: I'd really suggest you read up a bit on jQuery and how it works, seems your missing some valuable knowledge

Comment: man i think that the problem is not clearly. I have a index page that load the form when a button is pressed like register. Now in the new div with the form when i press send the page reloads all to the initial state and the div disappear. I have the basic principles of jquery, is not the problem

Comment: As i said in my post, when the form is loaded, you need to attach a submit even handler (or a click event handler to the send button) and do your ajax stuff, and you **must** prevent the default behaviour otherwise the form will submit itself (and reload the page as that's the default action)

Comment: yes i understand what you suggest. is the traditional way. i Will adapt my code. thanks